# maximum and minimum values of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

HI! I am currently working on some calc3 online homework problems and this one is giving me a bit of tough time. I found the gradient of f to be <16x,10y> and the gradient of g to be <4,20>. I used this information to solve for x and y and to obtain a critical point of (3/164, 6/41). Using the critical point and the original function I obtained the min value of 9/82. I am just a little lost on how to obtain the max value. If someone could help find the max value I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Rewrite the constraint as $y=\dfrac{3-4x}{20}$, replace on the objective function and conclude it doesn't have global maxima.

Comment: Thank you so much! @GitGud

Comment: No problem. It would be nice if you posted a complete solution if no one does so in a couple of days, so this question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: Another way to look at this is that the level curves of the function $ \ f(x,y) \ $ are concentric (similar) ellipses (centered on the origin), $ \ 8x^2 \ +  \ 5y^2 \ = \ c \ $ , which increase in "size" as the value of $ \ c \ $ increases.  The Lagrange-multiplier method "looks" for the level curve(s) which have a _tangent point_ to the constraint "curve", in this case, a straight line not passing through the origin.  There is some minimal value of $ \ c \ $ for which one of the ellipses is _just_ large enough to touch that line; that is the single result "Lagrange" will find. (continued)

Comment: So that is the value you correctly obtained.  However, larger values of $ \ c \ $ correspond to larger ellipses which intersect, but also pass beyond, the straight line. There are no _tangent_ points between these larger ellipses and the line, so "Lagrange" will say nothing about those.  There is also no limit to how large you can make these "level ellipses", so there is no maximal value for $ \ f(x,y) \ $ .  You can find a related problem discussed here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742674/use-lagrange-multipliers-to-find-the-absolute-extrema